# AWS Lambda - Search for a user in a cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm trying to write a pre signup lambda that will look for a user in our Cognito pool as to ensure that the data provided by the user is unique. I'm unable to find any docs that mention accessing the user pool directly or looking for a user by a non-username attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want using the ListUsers API call, it accepts a filter so that you can filter down to just the attributes you want to get!

Not a search in the most general sense, but should help you to accomplish what you want!

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html

Comment: Yup, that seems to be it, don't know how I wasn't able to find it, thank you very much!